# Free offline software to create vector+text graphical content

Tags: open-source, graphs, graphic-design

I want to create something like this:-

[image: example graphic 1]

And [image: example graphic 2]

Please provide your recommendations.

Comment: What o/s? Do you really mean `open source` (do you intend to change the source code), or [tag:gratis]? DO you have a preference for output format (.SVG, .PNG, .JPEG)?

Comment: I need it for WIndows O/S. I need a free to use software and not an online software. Output would be better if it is in JPEG,PNG but no specific preference

Comment: Is there a software other than Inkscape which is simple and easy to use? (for beginners)

Comment: Well, MS Paint would work ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This job seems easy to reach with Inkscape.

I took the liberty to upload some animated images, just to demonstrate that this program is versatile enough to create both the icons as well as the two charts.

[image]

[image]

For the second diagram, I used the Polar Grid extension to generate the nine spokes at equal intervals, but it is obvious that, depending on the experience of each user, the same result can be reached in different ways.

[image]

Of course, Inkscape can handle the text as well, as shown in the picture below. It's enough to attach the text of any curve / line type to get spectacular effects.

[image]

Of course, there are a number of graphical software as great as Inkscape, but I'll let the others to describe them in their posts.

But, believe me, they're all simple and easy to use (if you decipher their interface, toolbars, key combinations and working philosophy).

Every individual acquires these skills in no more than two hours of study.

The difference between one user and another makes it the experience gained from intense work. Every time I do something graphic with Inkscape, I get the desired result using a different or a new method, and that's exactly what I expect to offer me any kind of software...

Comment: Thank you very much. I think Inkscape is a good software for making these diagrams. Can I also write those texts inside these diagrams using the same software? As I know there are some softwares that don't allow you to write texts inside a diagram

Comment: Is there any software other than Inkscape which is simple and easy to use? (for beginners)

Comment: Well, MS Paint would work ...

Answer (score 3):

I use the open source Inkscape for vector graphics. It uses SVG as its native format, but exports to many formats, and can render PNG (bitmap) images from your vector drawings. (JPEG is not suited for these graphics, only for photos.)

This is a link to its own toturial on shapes, which includes working with circles and arcs: https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/shapes/tutorial-shapes.html

Comment: A screenshot showing Inkscape being used to make a circle arc would make this answer great. Please also mention that it is open source :-) The Paint.NET paragraph is not really needed, I guess, except if you suggest making the 3 icons seen in the first example with it. Thanks!

Comment: @NicholasRaoul Thank you for the suggestions, I replaced the second paragraph with a link to a relevant toturial. The icons should ideally be created as vector shapes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-platform (since you did not state an o/s), and open source, nothing beats the [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/).

See the extensive list of features [here](https://www.gimp.org/features/). It can certainly create the images which you show in your question.

---

[Update] as @Nicolas pointed out, you might prefer SVG (it helps us to help you if you tell us this sort of thing in your questions). In which case, the generally agreed best solution is [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/), which is cross-platform and free.

Comment: Wouldn't vector graphics be more adapted, though?

Comment: I would think so, which is why I asked for file formats in a comment above. For GIMP SVG, see [here]. But, if SVG is preferred, then the answer is probably [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/) I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @mawg the [here] has no link (GIMP SVG) and in the 'here' page from the answer thee is no mentioning of SVG.

Comment: Opos, sorry - https://docs.gimp.org/2.9/en/gimp-using-paths-and-svg.html

Comment: I need the software for WIndows O/S and the output format can be in any form. (JPEG,PNG,etc)

Comment: Well, MS Paint would work ...